# What is most efficieny way of updating a table with removing the old content from the memory?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following code:

```
class MyClass:

    def __init__(self):
        self.w = 2
        self.h = 2
        self.table = []

    def add_item(self, x, y, string_value):

        table0 = self.table
        if x >= self.w:
            self.w = x + 1
        if y >= self.h:
            self.h = y + 1

        self.table = [['foo' for h in range(self.h)] for w in range(self.w)]
        for i in range(0, len(table0)):
            for j in range(0, len(table0[i])):
                self.table[i][j] = table0[i][j]

        self.table[x][y] = string_value


def main():
    c = MyClass()
    c.add_item(7, 0, 'May')
    c.add_item(0, 5, 'June')
    c.add_item(2, 3, 'January')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This code takes the coordinates from the user to add a cell with a specific value to the table. To do so, if the coordinates are greater than the current table's dimension, then table's dimension will be updated accordingly.
I have two questions:

1. There is a nested loop in the *add_item* function to copy the previous content into the updated table. In terms of time complexity, isn't there a more efficient way to do that?
2. Each time when the table is updated, the previous content is still in the memory without being assigned to any variable, so how do I get rid of it? I know there is [Garbage Collector interface](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gc.html) in python, but I never used it before, if this is the correct way, how do I use it?

Thanks.

Comment: You do not "use" garbage collection. It happens automatically.

Comment: Note that if your code is already working correctly and you are looking for improvements, this seems more appropriate for [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) – be sure to check their [question guide](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2436/how-to-get-the-best-value-out-of-code-review-asking-questions) first, though.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi  Ok thanks. I can see there is a _Link to your post_ there, does it mean I still need to keep question here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be better to not recreate the list each time. Look at this version : only the needed cells are created dynamically while existing one are kept :

```
class MyClass:

    def __init__(self):
        self.w = 0
        self.h = 0
        self.table = []

    def add_item(self, x, y, string_value):

        while y >= self.h:
            for xx in range(self.w):
                self.table[xx].append(None)
            self.h = self.h + 1
          
        while x >= self.w:
            self.table.append([None] * self.h)
            self.w = self.w + 1
        
        self.table[x][y] = string_value


def main():
    c = MyClass()
    c.add_item(7, 0, 'May')
    c.add_item(0, 5, 'June')
    c.add_item(2, 3, 'January')
    print(c.table) #=>[[None, None, None, None, None, 'June'], [None, None, None, None, None, None], [None, None, None, 'January', None, None], [None, None, None, None, None, None], [None, None, None, None, None, None], [None, None, None, None, None, None], [None, None, None, None, None, None], ['May', None, None, None, None, None]]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Note also that a garbage collector is something doing its job automatically. Normally you don't have to worry about it.

Answer (score 0):

Modifying the existing list might be the better option.

```
def add_item(self, x, y, string_value, default_value=None):
    self.w = max(self.w, x)
    while len(self.table) <= self.w:
        self.table.append([])
    self.h = max(self.h, y)
    for line in self.table:
        while len(line) <= self.h:
            line.append(default_value)
    self.table[x][y] = string_value
```

---

Concerning the question about the garbage collector: Your data will be thrown away as soon as it is no longer referenced. The garbage collector is the last resort and can detect cyclic references of unused objects. When I started with Python I thought I would have to handle that memory management manually. In fact I never needed the `gc` module in over 15 years.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi. Thanks for the catch. I fixed that. I was considering an answer, where `w` and `h` are just read-only properties of the class. I don't see any reason to have them as writeable attributes.

Comment: @Matthias Thanks for your answer. In terms of time complexity, isn't it still O(n^2) based on the nested loop in your answer?

Comment: Yes, it is. In theory. But there is a difference between your solution and the one @dspr and I provided. If your table is 100*100 and you add something to position 90,90 you create a complete new table. We don't (and the solution of dspr even seems to be better than mine).